# Eureka Server Multiple instance by profile

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jakarta-ee, spring-cloud

I have created one eureka naming server. Where I have created 2 profiles. And registered those two profiles to each other.

My Application.yml is given below--

---

eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka/

---

spring:
  profiles: eureka-host1
server:
  port: 8761
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: eureka-host1
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://eureka-host2:8762/eureka/

---

spring:
  profiles: eureka-host2
server:
  port: 8762
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: eureka-host2
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://eureka-host1:8761/eureka/

---

After running the both profiles, if I hit the http://localhost:8761/ or http://localhost:8762/ I can see the both page of Spring Eureka Server. But there is no instance registered. But if I hit http://eureka-host1:8761/ or http://eureka-host2:8762/ then I can see "This site can’t be reached"

After a period of time I am getting the following message in the Spring-Eureka-Server -----

"EMERGENCY! EUREKA MAY BE INCORRECTLY CLAIMING INSTANCES ARE UP WHEN THEY'RE NOT. RENEWALS ARE LESSER THAN THRESHOLD AND HENCE THE INSTANCES ARE NOT BEING EXPIRED JUST TO BE SAFE."

Please help-----

My POM is given below-----

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com</groupId>
<artifactId>service-discovery-high-availability</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>rsmortgage-service-discovery-ha-latest</name>
<description>Spring Starter Project for Service Discovery for High Availability</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Dalston.SR1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: pls check your /etc/hosts file. Add your eureka-host1 and eureka-host2 to your hosts file.

Comment: Thanks. It's working now.